# Ver alterações (delete) na grid vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, delete

Olá, gostava que me ajudassem no seguinte.. eu tenho um form que faz uma pesquisa por um código com várias grids e um botão, esse botão faz uma série de alterações nas várias grids mas também quero eliminar umas certas linhas com uma query de delete que criei e, apesar de me apagar na BD (que é o que quero) também queria que as linhas desaparecessem da grid.. como é q faço para elas desaparecerem automaticamente quando clico no botão? é que só consigo ver a grid sem as linhas quando volto a inserir o código para a pesquisa. Obrigada

```
Public Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.Text = DGV1(5, 0).Value

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer



    ' para preencher a coluna do potencial de prescrição (id = 8 para 5), RankId(48 para Selecção)
    'Perfil linico = 8, GroupId = 8 (Categoria - Médicos) 


    For i = 0 To DGV3.Rows.Count - 1
        Select Case DGV3(2, i).Value
            Case 26
                DGV3(9, i).Value = 8
                DGV3(5, i).Value = 48
                DGV3(23, i).Value = 8
                DGV3(6, i).Value = 84

        End Select

    Next
    EscreveEnterpriseDetails()


    'para nr de clinicas


    Dim Obs As String
    Obs = Trim(DGV1(20, 0).Value.ToString)
    For j = 0 To DGV5.Rows.Count - 2

        If Obs = "" Then

            Obs = checknull(DGV5(6, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(7, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(8, j).Value.ToString)

        Else

            Obs = Obs & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & checknull(DGV5(6, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(7, j).Value.ToString) & " - " & checknull(DGV5(8, j).Value.ToString)

        End If


    Next

    ' MsgBox(Obs)


    DGV1(20, 0).Value = Obs
    DGV1(13, 0).Value = 0

    EscreverDoctorBasic()



    'para a morada 
    For j = 0 To DGV5.Rows.Count - 2
        DGV5(6, j).Value = "NÃO DEFINIDO" ' para a morada
        DGV5(7, j).Value = 421705           'para o codigo postal
        DGV5(8, j).Value = 0            'para o tipo local
        DGV5(9, j).Value = ""   ' para o horário
        DGV5(10, j).Value = True   ' visto para o LocalVisita

    Next
    EscreveAddress()

    ApagarRegistos()
```

Comment: Olá Mara, Vc deve chamar a grid novamente, para que ela atualize conforme os dados do banco de dados, faça isso após a função que ira deletar os registros do db

Comment: Uso o fill,é isso?

Comment: isso, aí depois vc atribui novamente os valores em seu datagrid.

Comment: é isso mesmo! Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Use o Fill para preencher sua datagrid, após deletar os dados do seu DB.